# bootstrap paragraph under image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a div with background image (SVG). I'm trying to make Bootstrap behave as if that background did not exist and be responsive as it should be, with that being said I want to write stuff over that background as if it wasn't there.

What the expected outcome here is that "test" is written over the background, not under it.

What am I missing?

```css
.firstsection {
  height: 70vh;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1200);
  background-size: cover;
}

.text {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
}

.secondsection {
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #151519;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="firstsection">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text">
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="secondsection">

</div>
```

Comment: Does the snippet demo above show the problem? I'm not sure I see what you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the parent element has a `background-image` meaning if you nest the text in the div with a background-image, it will go right over top. You can close the div with the background and start your `container` and `row` after that div.

I added a dummy image to demonstrate.

```css
.firstsection {
  height: 70vh;
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff);
  background-size: cover;
}

.text {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
}

.secondsection {
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #151519;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="firstsection"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text">
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="secondsection"></div>
```

If you want to keep relatively the same markup, remove the image from the background, and use the `img` tag. Then you can add the `flex-column` class. Then, to get it the same as the background image you can specify `width: 100%;` on the `img`. Finally, add `margin: 0;` to the body element, so it appears full-width as a background image would.

```css
.firstsection {
  height: 70vh;
  /*background-image: url(background.svg);*/
  background-size: cover;
}

.text {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
}

.secondsection {
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #151519;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstsection">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 w-100 flex-column text">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="secondsection">

</div>
```

Edit ~ made it so the text was on top of the background image.

```css
.firstsection {
  height: 70vh;
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.text {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
}

.secondsection {
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #151519;
}
```

```html
<!-- your index file should be structured like so -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="firstsection">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text">
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="secondsection">

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's the outcome of the code provided.
https://i.imgur.com/5BlXa5c.png

"test" should be ON the blue background, not below it.

Comment: @averagenewbie111 this do it for you?

Comment: edited my post above, sorry but it did not help me

Comment: @averagenewbie111 You can see how "bootstrap paragraph under image" would make me think you wanted the paragraph underneath. See my edits on my answer and view snippet #3. There is a dummy image in there to demonstrate the text over the background.

Comment: You see, that's exactly what I needed, third snippet works flawlessly, but the problem is that on my PC it still doesnt render it properly, but when I run the snipper here on stackoverflow it shows it properly. Could it be that i'm missing bootstrap files or something? Really weird stuff..

Comment: @averagenewbie111 that's because you need to include the Bootstrap stylesheet in your `head`.  ~ `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.....` See my edits and how it is structured, and place that into your HTML file and there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: That's not the case, I do have stylesheet in head, but i'll google what the problem could be so we avoid spamming this. Appreciate your time and answers!